# How do I update a single record from an spl server 2012 datatable using a c# datareader and a stored procedure?

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, datatable

I need to know how to update a single record from a sql server 2012 datatable using c# datareader and a stored procedure. I already have a stored procedure that allows me to update a single record in my datatable. I just can't figure out how to use a c# data reader to update a record in the datatable. For example, say I have a female student in a college class I'm teaching and she gets married, I would need to select her record from my student info datatable and change her last name to her new married name. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Why do you specifically say you need to use a datareader?

Comment: .Net datareader class - as its name suggests - is for reading data, not updating. So, no wonder you could not figure it out how to use it to update data. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254931(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

A `DataReader` is disconnected, read-only. That's why there aren't any methods for updating its values.

You said you have a stored procedure for updating. To execute that you would create the `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand` and add parameters just as you do when you execute the command that generates the `SqlDataReader`. But instead of calling `ExecuteReader()` you would typically call `ExecuteNonQuery()`. That's used for executing a query that doesn't return results. It returns the number of updated rows.

Comment: I'll give it a try. Thanks for the tip Mr. Hannen. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use DataReader in updating a record in SQL Server. Hence using stored procedure, you just have to declare a parameter in your stored procedure and pass a value to that parameter in C# like so:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[StoredProcedureName] 
    @SOMEPARAMETER AS VARCHAR(50)
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE tableName
    SET ColumnFromTable = @SOMEPARAMETER
    WHERE !--YourConditionGoesHere
END
GO
```

And in C# to pass the parameter do it like this:

```
using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("connectionSTringHere")
{
   SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("StoredProcedureName",con);
   cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
   cmd.Parameters.Add("@SOMEPARAMETER",SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "SomeValue";
   cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the example and detailed explanation Mr. Borlagdan. I'll use your example as a starting and see where it takes me.

Comment: and just for a shortcut that you wouldn't find in the internet.. if you're using SQL Server 2008 and above, you can go to object explorer  - dropdown your database - go to programmabaility right click on storedprocedures folder and click New, then just press CTRL + SHIFT M :D